# Debugview is shortening messages

Tags: windows, debugging

In Debugview and even in Debugview++ I get whery short messages and the longer ones end up with something like this.

```
..." (3188 characters)
```

Is there any way to get longer messages?

Answer (score 0):

look closely at the column header, the message column can de resized to show the whole message.
also the separator between the columns can be doubleclicked to size-to-fit.